# Matlab: How can I zoom in/out with multiple axes on a plot

Tags: matlab, zooming

I create a plot and add a top x-axis to it. The top x-axis is a parameter equivalent to bottom x-axis based on a relation. The problem is that when I zoom, the plot zooms only the second axes (the red one) and doesn't change the plot. I appreciate it if someone could help me to fix this problem.
Thank you in advance!

```
t = 0:0.05:10;               
S = cos(t);


figure; plot(t, abs(S));
box off
xlabel('Time (ns)')
ylabel('Amplitude')

Tm = (t+10)./(0.0032*2*pi);         %top x axis
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
hAx = gca;
hAx = axes('Position',hAx.Position,'XAxisLocation','top','YAxisLocation','right','color','none');
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
hAx.XLim            = [Tm(1) Tm(end)];
hAx.XTick           = linspace(Tm(1),Tm(end),11);
hAx.XColor          = 'r';
hAx.XLabel.String   = 'Equivalent Param.';
hAx.XLabel.FontSize = 10;
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
hAx.YColor     = 'r';
hAx.YTickLabel = ' ';
```

Comment: It might be easier to just edit the x tick labels to show both scales

Comment: Have you tried linkaxes? That might do what you need!  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html